# Errors on connection or with TLS between Xamatin client and Linux gRPC server

Tags: linux, xamarin, grpc, visual-studio-mac

I try to run a tipical example of gRPC from a Xamarin client (iOS and Android) to a Linux server (DietPi on a Raspberry) and I’m unable to get it works.
I use the next code from an [example from GitHub](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.46.x/examples/csharp/HelloworldXamarin).

But I also found [this page where it tells that it was not compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#net-grpc-client-requirements)

I'm confused.

The code I tried is the next:

**Server side code:**

appsettings.json

```
{
  "https_port": 7272,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    } /*,
    "EndPoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:7272"
      },
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:5081"
      }
    }*/
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using SolarServer.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
{
    Console.WriteLine("En macOS se deshabilita TLS.");
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        // Setup a HTTP/2 endpoint without TLS.
        options.ListenLocalhost(5081, o => o.Protocols =
            HttpProtocols.Http2);
    });
}

// Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
// For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

app.Run();
```

GreeterService.cs

```
using Grpc.Core;
using SolarServer;

namespace SolarServer.Services;

public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
    public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
        {
            Message = "Hello " + request.Name
        });
    }
}
```

greet.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "SolarServer";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "SolarServer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "applicationUrl": "http://10.0.0.138:5081;https://10.0.0.138:7272",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://10.0.0.138:5081;https://10.0.0.138:7272"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Xamarin client side code:**

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using SolarWizard.Models;
using SolarWizard.Services;
using SolarWizard.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SolarWizard
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Test.Instance.Do();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Test.cs

```
using System; using System.Collections; using System.Net; using System.Net.Http; using System.Net.Http.Headers; using System.Net.Security; using System.Security.Claims; using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; using System.Threading; using System.Threading.Tasks; using Grpc.Core; using Grpc.Net.Client; using SolarServer;

namespace SolarWizard {     public class Test/* : ICertificatePolicy*/
    {
        public static Test Instance { get; } = new Test();

        private Test() { }

        private Hashtable ht;

        public void Load()
        {
            if (ht == null)
            {
                ht = new Hashtable();
            }
            // TODO - use isolated storage so this will work even with
            // minimal security permissions
        }

        public void Save(int error, string thumbprint)
        {
            // TODO
        }

        public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int error)
        {
            if (error == 0)
                return true;
            // only ask for trust failure (you may want to handle more cases)
            if (error != -2146762486)
                return false;

            Load();
            string thumbprint = certificate.GetCertHashString();
            object result = ht[thumbprint];
            if ((result is int) && ((int)result == error))
                return true;

            Console.WriteLine("A trust error occured while attempting " +
                "to access the web site. Do you wish to:");
            Console.WriteLine("\ta) abort this untrusted session;");
            Console.WriteLine("\tb) continue this session (only once);");
            Console.WriteLine("\tc) trust this certificate with this " +
                "application (forever);");

            switch (Console.ReadLine().ToLower())
            {
                case "b":
                    return true;
                case "c":
                    Save(error, thumbprint);
                    return true;
                case "a":
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public async void Do()
        { /*
            AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

            CallCredentials credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) => Task.CompletedTask);
            //            var pp = new SslCredentials();
            //            var kk = ChannelCredentials.Create(pp, credentials);
            //            Channel channel = new Channel("https://10.0.0.3:7272", kk);
            //            Channel channel = new Channel("https://10.0.0.138:7272", ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials));  //           GrpcChannel channel;
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback; //System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
+= //delegate (object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, //                         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, //      System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) //{ //    return true; // **** Always accept //}; //            //channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://10.0.0.3:5081", new GrpcChannelOptions { Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure }); //            //channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://10.0.0.3:7272", new GrpcChannelOptions { Credentials = ChannelCredentials.SecureSsl }); // channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://10.0.0.3:7272");

            HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (a,b,c,d) => true};
            GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://10.0.0.3:7272", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
            Greeter.GreeterClient client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            HelloRequest request = new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" };
            HelloReply reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(request);
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
*/


/*
            //AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
            //AppContext.SetSwitch("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.EnableWindows81Http2", true);

            CallCredentials credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) => Task.CompletedTask);
            //            var pp = new SslCredentials();
            //            var kk = ChannelCredentials.Create(pp, credentials);
            //            Channel channel = new Channel("https://10.0.0.3:7272", kk);
            //            Channel channel = new Channel("https://10.0.0.138:7272", ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials)); //            GrpcChannel channel;
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback; //System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
+= //delegate (object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, //                         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, //      System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) //{ //    return true; // **** Always accept //};
            //channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://10.0.0.3:5081", new GrpcChannelOptions { Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure });
            //channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://10.0.0.3:7272", new GrpcChannelOptions { Credentials = ChannelCredentials.SecureSsl });

            //HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true };
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (message, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://10.0.0.3:7272", new GrpcChannelOptions());// { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
            Greeter.GreeterClient client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            HelloRequest request = new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" };
            HelloReply reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(request);
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
*/


/*
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (message, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            CallCredentials credentials2 = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
            {
                metadata.Add("Authorization", "Token");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { PreAuthenticate = false, ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true };
            GrpcChannel channel2 = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://10.0.0.3:7272", new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials2),
                HttpHandler = httpHandler
            }); ;
            Greeter.GreeterClient client2 = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel2);
            HelloRequest request2 = new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" };
                HelloReply reply2 = await client2.SayHelloAsync(request2);
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply2.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
*/


            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (message, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            CallCredentials credentials2 = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
            {
                metadata.Add("Authorization", "Token");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { PreAuthenticate = false, ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true };
            GrpcChannel channel2 = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://10.0.0.3:5081", new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure,
                HttpHandler = httpHandler
            }); ;
            Greeter.GreeterClient client2 = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel2);
            HelloRequest request2 = new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" };
                HelloReply reply2 = await client2.SayHelloAsync(request2);
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply2.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            //Return true if the server certificate is ok
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            bool acceptCertificate = true;
            string msg = "The server could not be validated for the following reason(s):\r\n";

            //The server did not present a certificate
            if ((sslPolicyErrors &
                 SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable)
            {
                msg = msg + "\r\n    -The server did not present a certificate.\r\n";
                acceptCertificate = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //The certificate does not match the server name
                if ((sslPolicyErrors &
                     SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)
                {
                    msg = msg + "\r\n    -The certificate name does not match the authenticated name.\r\n";
                    acceptCertificate = false;
                }

                //There is some other problem with the certificate
                if ((sslPolicyErrors &
                     SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
                {
                    foreach (X509ChainStatus item in chain.ChainStatus)
                    {
                        if (item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown &&
                            item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.OfflineRevocation)
                            break;

                        if (item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                        {
                            msg = msg + "\r\n    -" + item.StatusInformation;
                            acceptCertificate = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //If Validation failed, present message box
            if (acceptCertificate == false)
            {
                msg = msg + "\r\nDo you wish to override the security check?";
                //          if (MessageBox.Show(msg, "Security Alert: Server could not be validated",
                //                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
                acceptCertificate = true;
            }

            return acceptCertificate;
        }
        /*
        public bool MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(System.Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            bool isOk = true;
            // If there are errors in the certificate chain,
            // look at each error to determine the cause.
            if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainStatus.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (chain.ChainStatus[i].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
                    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
                    chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;
                    bool chainIsValid = chain.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);
                    if (!chainIsValid)
                    {
                        isOk = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return isOk;
        }*/
    }
}
```

The code commented is a part of tests I did but I can't make it works.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: In the client side is, with current code and comments the error is:
[ Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.") ] and in server no error is displayed.
But with other commented code the error is:
[ fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint. ]

Comment: Neither grpc-dotnet or Grpc.Core implementations of gRPC in C# support Xamarin officially. You might be able to get things working if you try hard enough (e.g. Grpc.Core definitely worked with Xamarin in the past), but the results are guaranteed (and you'd be on your own if it breaks). I'd recommend against using this in any production scenario.

Comment: Thank you. I will discard this way.