# Error trying to connect Xamarin app to firebase firestore using Google.Firebase.Firestore

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, grpc

I'm developing an app using xamarin and firestore as database.
But I get a error when I try to do it.
This is my code:

```
// get google json file
string fileName = "private_key.json";
var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(fileName);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    byte[] payload = ms.ToArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, fileName), payload);
}

var fileinfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, fileName));
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", fileinfo.FullName);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER", "native");
              
// Enable HTTP / 2 support
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

// Create a FirestoreDb instance
FirestoreDb databaseFS = FirestoreDb.Create("appname");

// Get a reference to a collection
CollectionReference collectionRef = databaseFS.Collection("Collection_Name");

// Create a new document with an auto-generated ID
DocumentReference documentRef = await collectionRef.AddAsync(new { Name = "John", Age = 30 });
```

and this is the error:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")
  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions+<>c_DisplayClass0_0`2[TRequest,TResponse].<WithRetry>b0 (TRequest request, Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.CallSettings callSettings) [0x0016f] in //Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ApiCallRetryExtensions.cs:39 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.WriteBatch.CommitAsync (Google.Protobuf.ByteString transactionId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00080] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/WriteBatch.cs:226 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference.CreateAsync (System.Object documentData, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/DocumentReference.cs:106 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.CollectionReference.AddAsync (System.Object documentData, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00044] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/CollectionReference.cs:94
```

Why I get this error? How can I solve it? Google.Firebase.Firestore should be compatible with xamarin..

Comment: A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75862796) recently included a reference to a [compatibility matrix for `Grpc.Net.Client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#net-grpc-client-requirements) that shows Xaramin does not "have required HTTP/2 support" which concurs with your error "downgraded to HTTP/1.1"

Answer (score 1):

Please verified your server has HTTP/2 enabled. if you aren't using TLS then a port can't use HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2. It can only use HTTP/2.

You can check [Troubleshoot gRPC on .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more information.