# GRPC problem connecting Android device to Firebase usign Google.Cloud.Firebase in .Net Maui

Tags: c#, android, firebase, grpc, maui

I'm developing a mobile application in .Net Maui and using Firebase as DB. To connect to the db I'm using the 'Google.Cloud.Firestore' and 'Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1' libraries. For iOS is all fine but when I try to Android, I get this error:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: net_http_requested_version_cannot_establish, 2.0, RequestVersionOrHigher, 2", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: net_http_requested_version_cannot_establish, 2.0, RequestVersionOrHigher, 2
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ThrowGetVersionException(HttpRequestMessage , Int32 , Exception )
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken )
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.<RunCall>d__73[[Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.RunQueryRequest, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0],[Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.RunQueryResponse, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0]].MoveNext()")
at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.AsyncResponseStream`1.<MoveNextAsync>d__8[[Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.RunQueryResponse, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0]].MoveNext()
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<<ForEachAsync>g__Core|99_0>d`1[[Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.RunQueryResponse, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0]].MoveNext()
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<<ForEachAsync>g__Core|99_0>d`1[[Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.RunQueryResponse, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=185c282632e132a0]].MoveNext()
at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.GetSnapshotAsync(ByteString transactionId, CancellationToken cancel
```

I don't know why but I get this error only with some Android devices not all.(I think it depends on the age).

I tried to put [this line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867874/error-trying-to-connect-xamarin-app-to-firebase-firestore-using-google-firebase)

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
```

but with no success.